# android :filter is not working in costum gridview adapter

Tags: android, gridview, filter

i'm trying to make a simple app wish where i've got a gridview and a edittext and when i type in the edittext it filters the gridview enter code here

```
class CostumAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Personne> implements Filterable{
    Costumfilter filter;
    ArrayList <Personne> filterlist;
    ArrayList <Personne> items;
    public CostumAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <Personne> items) {
        super(context,R.layout.costum_row,items);
        this.filterlist=items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View costumview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_row, parent, false);
        Personne imed=getItem(position);
        TextView mytext = (TextView) costumview.findViewById(R.id.mytext1);
        mytext.setText(imed.firstname);
        mytext.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
        return  costumview;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(filter == null){
            filter=new Costumfilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    public int getRandomColor(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }

    class Costumfilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()!=0){
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<Personne> filters =new ArrayList<Personne>();
                for (int i=0; i <filterlist.size();i++){
                    //probleme peut etre ici
                    if (filterlist.get(i).firstname.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        Personne p =new Personne(filterlist.get(i).firstname,filterlist.get(i).lastname,filterlist.get(i).number,filterlist.get(i).mail);
                        filters.add(p);
                    }
                    if (filterlist.get(i).firstname.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        Personne p =new Personne(filterlist.get(i).firstname,filterlist.get(i).lastname,filterlist.get(i).number,filterlist.get(i).mail);
                        filters.add(p);
                    }
                }
                results.count=filters.size();
                results.values=filters;
            }else{
                results.count=filterlist.size();
                results.values=filterlist;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            items=(ArrayList<Personne>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
 }
```

this is my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Personne> items = new ArrayList<Personne>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    EditText textfilter =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textfilter);

    items.add(new Personne("kabouya","imed","0553164597","haha95@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("Tazir","oussama","0654613257","oussamaMail@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("kabouya","imed","0553164597","haha95@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("Tazir","oussama","0654613257","oussamaMail@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("kabouya","imed","0553164597","haha95@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("Tazir","oussama","0654613257","oussamaMail@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("kabouya","imed","0553164597","haha95@live.fr"));
    items.add(new Personne("Tazir","oussama","0654613257","oussamaMail@live.fr"));

    final CostumAdapter adapter = new CostumAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);

    GridView mygrid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.mygrid);
    mygrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    mygrid.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    textfilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence ss, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(ss.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    mygrid.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String  someone=String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
                    TextView textnum =(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textnum);
                    TextView textmail =(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textmail);
                    TextView maintext =(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.maintext);
                    maintext.setText(items.get(i).firstname.toString()+" "+items.get(i).lastname.toString());
                    textnum.setText(items.get(i).number.toString());
                    textmail.setText(items.get(i).mail.toString());
                    mBuilder.setView(mView);
                    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

this is a school project and it has due date so pls help me :)

Comment: what are your findings until now? are you sure that the filtering is working and publishResults is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have not overrided `getItem`, therefore the adapter is getting the data from an unmodified list.

Try with these changes

```
public CostumAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <Personne> items) {
    super(context,R.layout.costum_row,items);
    this.filterlist = items;
    this.items = items; //initially you want to show all items
}

...

@Override
public Personne getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}
```

And probably you also need to override `getCount()`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

Comment: The filterring isnt working when I write in the édit text nothing happens

Comment: @ImadKby still not working?

Comment: I overrided the methodes but still it isnt filltering  :( @diedu

Comment: Wait it's working now my problem was I was having 2 tests one if it contains the constraint and an other if it stars with the constraint thanks men youre a life saver